Searching for a woman
I'm looking for the name of a film. It's about this man and a boy looking for a woman (she either has amnesia or is on the run). The film shows their journey looking for her. They found her in a big city that they traveled to to find her and she works in a sort of sex shop (putting on shows behind glass for men). The man keeps going to see her, then I think he saves her somehow.   
I think it was set in the 70's/80's. Don't recognise the actors. I remember a scene where the man first sees her in the sex shop thing. She's behind glass, she can't see him, but he can see her and she had black hair. Definitely American.

What year\decade was it from? Was it American? Did you recognize any of the actors? Do you remember anything else about the plot or other specific scenes? [And BTW, are you absolutely sure it's the woman who suffers from amnesia?]

im not sure if she has amnesia or is just on the run/hiding. I think it was set in the 70's/80's. Don't recognise the actors. I remember a scene where he first sees her in the sex shop thing. She's behind glass, she can't see him, but he can see her, she had black hair. Definitely American. That's all I can remember

They found her in a big city that they traveled to to find her

"she had black hair" Ah, it was Paris, Texas from 1984 till you said that. Back to the drawing board...

Sound like Paris, Texas from 1984.

After an absence of 4 years, Travis Henderson suddenly reappears in a deserted part of south Texas. His brother Walt fetches him and he is soon reunited with his son Hunter. He can't really explain why he's been away or why he's suddenly reappeared. Walt has been raising Travis' son Hunter and it takes a while for the two of them to get reacquainted. They eventually set off together to find Jane, Travis' wife and Hunter's mother. She is found working in a peep show in Houston but a happy family reunion isn't in the cards.

Here you can see trailer.

What I had mind as well. It fits most of the criteria. +1

Thank you so much!!!! I could kiss you. Driving me mental. Much appreciated. :D

@Brad You're welcome. All details have come together, except black hair...:)

BTW @Brad, if this is the correct answer, don't forget to approve it by clicking on the check mark.
